# Javascript вернуться в начало кода

Tags: javascript

```
var x = prompt("Гони число от 1 до 3!");
if (x == 2) alert ("Молодца!");
else alert ("Неверно!");
```

Для того чтобы снова ввести число, нужно обновить страничку. Можно ли сделать, чтобы после неверного ответа программа сама снова предлагала ввести число? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var x;
while (x != "2") {
  x = prompt("Гони число от 1 до 3!");
  if (x == 2) {
    alert ("Молодца!");
  } else {
    alert ("Неверно!");
  }
}
```

`!=` - означает "не равно"

```js
var x;
for (; x != "2"; ) {
  x = prompt("Гони число от 1 до 3!");
  if (x == 2) {
    alert ("Молодца!");
  } else {
    alert ("Неверно!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Если Вас не затруднит, можно узнать: 1. можно ли в такой ситуации использовать цикл for? 2. Что означает "!="?

Comment: Еще раз большое спасибо!